# Can jquery-ias be used for 2 lists on 1 page?

Tags: jquery-ias

Anyone have a solution for 2 lists on 1 page using jquery-ias? 
or any other infinite scroller for that matter.

Regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IAS has the solution!

Add 2 divs with css `overflow-y: auto;` and add the following configuration in javascript:

```
$("#container1").ias({
  container:  "#container1",
  item:       ".item",
  pagination: "#pagination1",
  next:       ".next a",
});

$("#container2").ias({
  container:  "#container2",
  item:       ".item",
  pagination: "#pagination2",
  next:       ".next a",
});
```